# кнопка с иконкой внутри

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть bootstrap кнопка

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">button <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

в ней иконка от FontAvesome. Как сделать так, чтоб при наведении указателя мыши, кнопка растягивалась по оси Х и в ней появлялась иконка, при отводе указателя - скрывалась
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально скрыть иконку и отображать при наведении курсора мыши, т.е. :hover

```css
.btn-danger {
  overflow: hidden; /* скрываем все содержимое кнопки выходящее за ее пределы */
  position: relative;
  transition: all 250ms ease; /* задаем анимацию для всех трансформаций */
}
.btn-danger:hover {
  padding-right: 25px; /* по наведению на кнопку увеличиваем правый отступ, чтобы влезла иконка */
}
.btn-danger .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  right: -25px; /* изначально прячем иконку за пределами кнопки (за пределами мы ее не видим, т.к. выше определили для .btn-danger{overflow:hidden;}) */
  transition: all 250ms ease;  /* для иконки тоже задаем анимацию для всех трансформаций */
}
.btn-danger:hover .fa {
  right: 7px; /* меняем положение таким образом, чтобы иконка приняла необходимую позицию */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">button <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: как тоже самое сделать с кнопкой в форме    `<input type="reset" class="btn active" value=" сброс "/>`

Comment: есть пара идей:
1. Анимировать background-image
2. Скрыть кнопку, создать объект по типу приведенному в ответе выше и с помощью jQuery перехватывать клик по нему и эмулировать клик по нужной кнопке...
Что-то типа
````$('#new-button').on('click', function(){$('#your-button').trigger('click');});````

Answer (score 1):

```
.btn-danger i {
    display: none;
}

.btn-danger:hover i {
    display: block;
}
```